# barstate.isrealtime not working in replay mode

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, replay

barstate.isrealtime not working as I expected.

When it comes to my understanding `barstate.isrealtime == false` is not working in replay mode. Its working until I click on the replay as it may simulates realtime bars so the statement instantly changes to true.

What is the proper way to use it? or how can I disable barstate data when using replay? or maybe a way to check is replay mode active?

As my script is using request security from different timeframes with different datas of bars and organize it to a table. Its working good until I hop into replay mode and playing the bars back. Its showing inconsistent datas as usual so thats why I want to ignore it and delete the table in replay mode but do not know how.
Tried barstate.ishistory also, but same story.

```
if barstate.isrealtime == false
        table.delete(tabledatas)
```

Many thanks in advance!

---

@Mario - here is an example table, I tried what you advised but it always shows the `barstate.islast data.`

```
var table tabl1 = table.new('middle' + '_' + 'center', 2, 2, border_color = auto_bg, border_width = 1, frame_color = auto_bg, frame_width = 1)
if barstate.isfirst
    table.cell(tabl1, 0, 0, 'currentvalue' , 0, 0, #ffffff, 'center', text_size=size.huge, bgcolor=color.new(#000000, 0))
    table.cell(tabl1, 1, 0, 'currentvalue' , 0, 0, #ffffff, 'center', text_size=size.huge, bgcolor=color.new(#000000, 0))

else if barstate.islast
    table.cell_set_text(tabl1, 0, 0, 'replayvalue')
    table.cell_set_text(tabl1, 1, 0, 'replayvalue')
```

replayvalue = can be anything as I will surely put a '-' to it as I do not want to show up any inconsistent value when user in replay mode.
So if chart data is real time I want to show 'currentvalue' if replay mode then 'replayvalue'.

```
if barstate.islast
    var table tabl1 = table.new('middle' + '_' + 'center', 2, 2, border_color = auto_bg, border_width = 1, frame_color = auto_bg, frame_width = 1)
    if barstate.ishistory
        table.cell(tabl1, 0, 0, 'replayvalue' , 0, 0, #ffffff, 'center', text_size=size.huge, bgcolor=color.new(#000000, 0))
        table.cell(tabl1, 1, 0, 'replayvalue' , 0, 0, #ffffff, 'center', text_size=size.huge, bgcolor=color.new(#000000, 0))
    else if barstate.isrealtime
        table.cell(tabl1, 0, 0, 'currentvalue' , 0, 0, #ffffff, 'center', text_size=size.huge, bgcolor=color.new(#000000, 0))
        table.cell(tabl1, 1, 0, 'currentvalue' , 0, 0, #ffffff, 'center', text_size=size.huge, bgcolor=color.new(#000000, 0))
```

@Mario Here is the updated code based on your reply, but it is doing the same as the first time I did the script. It's okay in real time it shows 'currentvalue', when switching to replay mode it shows 'replayvalue' but when playing the bars in replay mode it shows the 'currentvalue' instead of 'replayvalue' again.

Answer (score 0):

`barstate.isrealtime` is for live data, so it should not work with replay which uses historical data.
But replay changes `barstate`, why I don't know, in fact no body does, (except the DEVs).

I would use this for strategies when going live, but not for backtesting.

the proper way to initialize tables is...

```
if barstate.isfirst
    table.cell(...)
else if barstate.islast
    table.cell_set_*()
```

`barstate.isfirst` will update the table once only at the beginning of the script,
and `barstate.islast` will update the table every time the script is at the most right candle/bar.

Here are examples of all `barstates` from the [user manual](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Bar_states.html#example)...

```
//@version=5
indicator("Bar States", overlay = true, max_labels_count = 500)

stateText() =>
    string txt = ""
    txt += barstate.isfirst     ? "isfirst\n"     : ""
    txt += barstate.islast      ? "islast\n"      : ""
    txt += barstate.ishistory   ? "ishistory\n"   : ""
    txt += barstate.isrealtime  ? "isrealtime\n"  : ""
    txt += barstate.isnew       ? "isnew\n"       : ""
    txt += barstate.isconfirmed ? "isconfirmed\n" : ""
    txt += barstate.islastconfirmedhistory ? "islastconfirmedhistory\n" : ""

labelColor = switch
    barstate.isfirst                => color.fuchsia
    barstate.islastconfirmedhistory => color.gray
    barstate.ishistory              => color.silver
    barstate.isconfirmed            => color.orange
    barstate.isnew                  => color.red
    => color.yellow

label.new(bar_index, na, stateText(), yloc = yloc.abovebar, color = labelColor)
```

Sorry, as of my knowledge there seems to be no way to check between replay and live chart.
Why would anyone want that to know anyway.
If you have unreliable backtest data, then you should check your code!
Cause it should work all the same, except when using `varip`.

---

The closest you will get is using some like this ...

```
if timenow > time and barstate.isrealtime
    label.new(bar_index, high, "Live")
else
    label.new(bar_index, high, "history")
```

It uses time to see if its live data or historical data.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, btw something is not working here as an example. It always shows the else if data. Can you, please have a look? Just a quick example code of what Ive used.

Comment: @trashasf don't use comments to put important code in it, instead use the [EDIT Button](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77206815/edit) to update your post, so other people can help you too.

Comment: Mario, thanks. I've just edited the post. Can you, please have a look at what could be the problem and what should be a kind of solution?

Comment: @trashasf  please give me more context and more code to look at. And I update my post accordingly too.

Comment: It is pretty much the code that I'm using, just with more detailed values. I want to show up a table with data 'A' on the real-time chart. But if replay mode is active I want to see 'A' data to switch to 'B'. 

And if I'm using it like you mentioned (with `barstate.isfirst & last` it always shows the 'B' data in real-time too if you may try to use the script in the question. Hope it's understandable and really hope you can help me.

Comment: @trashasf for this case you have to insert a second `if` statement inside the local scope of `else if barstate.islast`, and use your condition `A` and `B` to select from

Comment: Thank you for your reply, at this time what should be the second if statement (what barstate value or?)? I'm not sure I got what you really meant by. I updated the code in the question, with 'currentvalue' and 'replayvalue'. Can you please update your answer on what you actually meant?

Comment: Thank you again, checked your answer and I’ve updated the code in the question according to your comment but it is still not working as expected. :(

Comment: @trashasf what do you expect the values to be?

Comment: as I said I would like to have 'replayvalue' in Replay mode even if I'm playing the bars in replay mode. So I only need 'currentvalue' in real-time and do not want to get this value in replay mode when playing the bars.

In other words, the table should only show in real-time, otherwise (replay, replay mode) shows nothing

Comment: @trashasf my answer is correct, when you don't want to see the table in the replay mode, than don't put any thing into the local scope of `if barstate.ishistory`

Comment: Can you, please post the whole code in your answer (with my example) as you think about it? As I tried different ways based on your answers but still did work as expected, as I described. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Based on your code It shows the 'historical' value in replay mode if I jump to a specific time, or if I play forward in replay mode it still shows the 'currentvalue'. So far still everything the same from my very first question. :( Have you tried it?

Comment: @trashasf sorry, you were right and I was wrong. I updated my post.

Comment: tried a lot of ways but still can't find a decent solution. But thanks for the effort and attempts.